# Visual C# Windows form Application dont know how to complete this question

Tags: c#

When squirrels get together for a party they like to eat acorns. A squirrel party is
successful when the number of acorns is between 40 and 60, inclusive unless it is
the weekend, in which case there is no upper limit on the number of acorns. Write
a program which will find out when the party is and how many acorns there are.
Return “Good Party” if the party is within the rules or “Terrible Party” if they have
the wrong number of acorns.

I have done the part of the number of acorns but struggling in the weekend part also I am new to this 
This is my code

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int acorns = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            if (acorns >= 40 && acorns  <= 60)
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Good Party");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Terrible Party");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should check the current day if it's within the weekend or not. For this you can use: System.DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString();  which will returns the current day name.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It looks like you need help with some kind of code challenge! Thanks for providing a code sample, is this an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) so we can copy/paste and begin helping you? Also it doesn't look like you have a problem statement other than "don't know how to complete the question." What specific issues are you having trouble with? What input do you get and what output are you expecting? What do you get instead? These kinds of things help the community better find answers for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just check the dayofweek on the date which you are working. Here i use system date

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int acorns = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            if (acorns >= 40 && (System.DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || System.DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday || acorns  <= 60))
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Good Party");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Terrible Party");
            }
        }
```

Comment: thanks it helped me but its not allowing me to upvote this might be because iam new to stackoverflow.

Comment: @Syed-MuhammadJAFFERY probably thats the reason

Answer (score -1):

To find the day of the week use `DateTime.DayOfWeek`

Comment: This is more of a comment, rather than an answer. If you would like to leave this an answer I would encourage to provide more detail as to why and how this answers the question.